# How to do something if checkbox is selected?

Tags: java, swing

I have a swing GUI, I'm trying to get my GUI to close if a certain requirement is met only if the checkbox is checked
`JCheckBox C1 = new JCheckBox("checkbox 1");` 
so the code should be something like 
`if(Jcheckbox is pressed) //do something`

if that makes sense

Comment: You use the `isSelected()` method of the `JCheckBox`.

Comment: There are decent tutorials for this: [JCheckBox and JButton Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(c1.isSelected()){
    // your code
}
```

or use event if you want to do some action when the selection happens

```
myCheckBox.addItemListener((ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //do something...
        } else {//checkbox has been deselected
            //do something...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hey this helped thanks, but how would i do this? if (C1.isSelected()&&t1.getText()>=350){
   System.exit(1); } how would i do this?

Comment: if(C1.isSelected() && t1.getText() != null &&t1.getText().length() >= 350) { System.exit(1); }